# Create and use test License for SPA on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, licensing

I am trying to test my license authentication code for a SPA on SharePoint online. I know that this is technically vulnerable due to the client-side nature of the code but I would like to keep this in JavaScript if I can.

So far I have tried following this example from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp123519.aspx
but I don't have the file 'OfficeAppManifests' that I need to add the .tok to.

This license importing app from Microsoft: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Import-f5f680a6

This application from codeplex: spapplicensecreator (sorry no link because SE won't let me)
but this wouldn't even make it past the login step.

I have been attempting to do this for the past couple of days and my research keeps leading me in circles back to the same snippets of code over and over. It seems like there should be a simple way to do this if Microsoft wants people to make apps for their store.